# Become "the real administrator"(Windows) and perform real admin tasks in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, admin, task

In Windows just because your account is in the Administrators group doesn't mean it is privileged enough to be able to delete **some** system files. Is there a way to perform actions with this '**supreme**' admin power in C# without having to login to Administrator account(Only using an account in the Administrators group).

**EDIT**

In my case it is a personal application (I'm sorry I didn't specify this) and I trust myself to not delete any system files or give any rogue virus access to this privilege. I am using a domain account on a personal computer and while I have got Administrator on my personal computer I don't want to keep switching between users. What I want is a simple way of running my program as the highest possible privileged user. Is there no way whatsoever unless logged in as a full Administrator?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: What are these **some** system files that you want to delete and why? Please elaborate. May be a better solution would come up!

Comment: @Mayank Well I don't actually want to edit any system files. I just want to make sure I have full system power in my application routine. @Lloyd I suppose but if you can do it in linux with the sudo command why shouldn't Windows be able to do it.

Comment: @Liam: All administrators on Windows have the same rights, unlike `root` in Linux. If your program is getting blocked due to UAC, consider adding a [UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), not impersonating an account.

Comment: Are you talking about elevation in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Comment: @Liam E-p Generally speaking, it's an incredibly bad idea to run an application with super duper Administrator powers. Have you considered whether your app *really* needs them? See [the principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Comment: Doesn't elevation require you to log in as an Administrator? Not into the desktop but even to perform the operation if you're not elevated? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx

Comment: In my case it is a personal application (I'm sorry I didn't specify this) and I trust myself to not delete any system files or give any rogue virus access to this privilege. I am using a domain account on a personal computer and while I have got Administrator on my personal computer I don't want to keep switching between users. What I want is a simple way of running my program as the highest possible privileged user.

Comment: There is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx, but seems it will still prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question Answered thanks. I have been informed that there is no possible way of launching an application with **FULL** administrator rights as you can in Linux with the sudo command. Adding a UAC manifest was helpful though as it specified how to implement rights into my app(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

//closed

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.  You should still mark it as the preferred answer.

Comment: There's nothing that LocalSystem can do that administrators can't.  So I'm a bit confused about your "there is no possible way of launching an application with FULL administrator rights".  You might have to take some extra steps (to modify one of the few files that administrator doesn't have access to) but you can do anything you want to as an administrator.

Comment: One other thought: Even LocalSystem doesn't have "full" administrator rights.  Unlike *nix where root has an AuthN bypass, in Windows LocalSystem can be locked out (by removing NTAUTHORITY\System from an ACL).  Of course LocalSystem can always get access to the resources (by enabling the TakeOwnership privilege) but...

Comment: That is not true. Just google a bit for "Start program as system". System has every possible right. System can even read the password hashes of the users.